# accessing a form that is in an iframe

Tags: javascript, forms, iframe

I'm trying to get access to a form and its elements. The form is within an iframe and the javascript code that is accessing the form is within the main document.

I'm not sure what else I should put into the question, so please let me know if I need to add something else.

(form and main page are in the same domain)

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
var ifr = document.getElementById( yourIframeId );
var ifrDoc = ifr.contentDocument || ifr.contentWindow.document;
var theForm = ifrDoc.getElementById( yourFormId );
```

Or you could have some code in the frame that sets a variable in `parent` to the form, but I wouldn't trust that method.

Comment: Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin , it won't work for Two different domains.

Comment: do you have any suggestion to make this work for cross domains also ?

Comment: Try it as bookmarklet or TamperMonkey script - Its DTP plugin works even in Kiwi on Android. Made answer with working example (except formatted to multiple lines for readability)

Answer (score 3):

If your iframe has a `name` attribute, that can be used as a window name. If the frame name is "myframe":

```
myframe.document.getElementById("myform") // gives you the form element
```

Comment: You can also use frame ID to get the element by ID, just as you did with getting the form by ID from the frame.  Of course, the form has to have an ID also.

Answer (score 1):

Just made bookmarklet based on my older post
[Is it possible to save form data to a data file on the local computer and then reload that text file back into a form to select those same items?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61274853/is-it-possible-to-save-form-data-to-a-data-file-on-the-local-computer-and-then-r/61320219#61320219)

It is reads inside iframe and set result JSON to textarea and prints to console:

```js
javascript:o=document.getElementById("wf_IFid").contentDocument;
f=o.getElementsByTagName("input"), longest=f.length;
frm=f;
values={};
p=0;
for(a=0;a<longest;a++){
  el=frm[a];
  switch(el.type){
    case "checkbox":
      values[el.name]=el.checked;
      break;
    case "radio":
      if(el.checked)values[el.name]=el.value;
      else if(values[el.name]===undefined)values[el.name]=false;
      break;
    case "select-one":
      values[el.name]=el.selectedIndex<0?-1:el.options[el.selectedIndex].value;
      break;
    case "select-multiple":
      values[el.name]=[];
      for(i=0;i<el.options.length;i++){
        if(el.options[i].selected)values[el.name].push(el.options[i].value)
      }
      break;
    case "fieldset":
      break;
    case "button":
      break;
    case "submit":
      break;
    case "reset":
      break;
    case "file":
      break;
    case undefined:
      break;
    default:
      {
        if(el.getAttribute("aria-label")&&el.value){
          key=p++ + "|" + el.getAttribute("aria-label");
          values[key]=el.value
        }
      }
  }
}
t=o.createElement("textarea");
t.value=JSON.stringify(values, null, 2);
o.body.prepend(t);
console.log(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
```