# get the element inside of iframe

Tags: javascript, html, events, wordpress

I want to get body element 'tinymce' which positioned inside iframes as the tree shown below..

html -> body -> div#wpwrap -> div#wpcontent -> div#wp-content -> div#wrap -> form#post -> div#editorcondainer -> div#poststuff -> div#post-body -> div#post-body-content -> div#postdivrich -> **div#editiorcontainer** -> **span#content_parent** -> table#content_tbl.mceLayout -> tbody -> tr -> td.mceIframeContainer.mceFirst.mceLast -> **iframe#content_ifr** -> html -> **body#tinymce.mceContentBody**

For that i uses the code :

```
 var iframeEl = document.getElementById('content_ifr');
 alert(iframeEl);

 if ( iframeEl.contentDocument ) { // DOM

  var bdy = iframeEl.contentDocument.getElementById('tinymce');

 } else if ( iframeEl.contentWindow ) { // IE win

  var bdy = iframeEl.contentWindow.document.getElementById('tinymce');

 }
```

But iframeE1 is null :(

Im trying other ids in the tree but it stop returning elements from the 'span id :content_parent', the last id returning object is 'div id :editorcontainer'

How could i get the elements after 'span id :content_parent'

Answer (score 2):

Try `document.getElementById('content_ifr');` The code above looks for `document.getElementById(undef);` (since you never define a variable called `content_ifr`).

Comment: I tried in that way too.. But still its returning null. So iframeEl is null & execution of further makes errors.... :(

Comment: If it returns null, then there is no element with that ID in the current document. Also check the JavaScript error console; maybe there is another bug.

Comment: Im trying other ids in the tree but it stop returning elements from the 'span id :content_parent', the last id returning object is 'div id :editorcontainer'

How could i get the elements after 'span id :content_parent'

Comment: Just like you would with every other element in the same document; the bug must be elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

The `<iframe>` creates a new window context with a new document. So give the `<iframe>` a name attribute like `name="somename"` so you can access it like this:

```
window.somename.document.getElementById('tinymce')
```

If you don't have access to the HTML you could first add the name via JS like this:

```
document.getElementById('tinymce').setAttribute('name','somename');
```

Some digging on SO brought up this: [accessing a form that is in an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478078/accessing-a-form-that-is-in-an-iframe) which explains how to do this with only an ID. That should sum up the possibilities.

Comment: <iframe id="content_ifr" src='javascript:""' frameborder="0" style="width: 100%; height: 135px; "></iframe>


Is there way to add name to the iframe or can u please explain a way to use above syntax using its id...

Comment: Use `<iframe name='xxx' ...`. After that, the `iframe` should be accessible via `window.xxx`. I'm not sure how browser compliant that is, though. `getElementById()` should work in any browser.

Comment: i cannot edit the content in iframe tag, coz im not the person who create it. Thats why im trying to access via its id. Is there a way to add a name to that iframe outside of its iframe tags of is there a way to access the iframe by its id..

Answer (score 0):

If the source of the `iframe` is not in the same domain as the the containing page, you will not have access to the iframe's contents, as they're in differing security sandboxes.

Comment: does it means i have not any options left to access that element 'tinymce'

Comment: Only if you're trying to perform cross-domain access. Imagine if you could embed an iframe with a bank's login page. You could write some script to grab the autofill data from any users who happen to use that bank.