# Call method inside VM of Silverlight application on click of CRM Ribbon button

Tags: silverlight-4.0, mvvm, dynamics-crm-2011, ribbon-control

We are planning to use Silverlight MVVM application in Dynamics 2011 for few custom features. We also want to have consistent looks for whole application for both Dynamics and Silverlight modules. That’s why we are creating web resource to host this Silverlight application inside CRM.

Now problem is we need to create “Save”, “Edit” etc buttons in Ribbon, which in-turn behaves like buttons inside Silverlight module. Following are important questions

1. Can we create such buttons in Ribbon to access methods inside View Model of Silverlight application hosted using “Web resource”. These methods will also have to access data changes done by user in Silverlight Views.
2. Is there any other better way to handle such situation

Thanks,

Nilesh

Comment: Added the blog post on Geekswithblogs too - [Link](http://geekswithblogs.net/Nilesh/archive/2011/08/25/call-c-code-inside-silverlight-application-on-click-of-custom.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I’ve successfully called the function inside C# code of Silverlight application from Ribbon button click.

Here is the screenshot of final output.

[image: OutPut]

**Here is what PoC is doing**

1. There is Silverlight application hosted in CRM on custom area-subarea. This in-turn needs two web resources
2. There is Custom button added in Ribbon
3. Third web resource is hosting JavaScript function
4. On click of Custom Button on CRM Ribbon function in JavaScript web resource is called which in-turn calls the method in C# code of Silverlight application. String input is passed to this method
5. C# method is converting the input string to upper case and returning it.
6. Finally alert is displayed with upper case string.

**Here are the details to create the PoC**

1. Created new solution in CRM
2. Created new Area and Sub-Area for this PoC by editing Site Map XML. Here is the XML added in customizations.xml.
3. Added custom button in Application Ribbon. Here is the updated XML for Ribbon

   Sequence="101">
4. Created Silverlight Application. Here is important C# code.

> Note
>   System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.RegisterScriptableObject("SilverlightCode",
>   this); and  [ScriptableMember]

```
public partial class MainPage : UserControl
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.RegisterScriptableObject("SilverlightCode", this);                                
        }

        // After the Frame navigates, ensure the HyperlinkButton representing the current page is selected
        private void ContentFrame_Navigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (UIElement child in LinksStackPanel.Children)
            {
                HyperlinkButton hb = child as HyperlinkButton;
                if (hb != null && hb.NavigateUri != null)
                {
                    if (hb.NavigateUri.ToString().Equals(e.Uri.ToString()))
                    {
                        VisualStateManager.GoToState(hb, "ActiveLink", true);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        VisualStateManager.GoToState(hb, "InactiveLink", true);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // If an error occurs during navigation, show an error window
        private void ContentFrame_NavigationFailed(object sender, NavigationFailedEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            ChildWindow errorWin = new ErrorWindow(e.Uri);
            errorWin.Show();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(CustomMethod("Silverlight Button Clicked !"));
        }

        //This method will be called from JavaScript on click of Ribbon Button
        //This method needs to be Public
        [ScriptableMember]
        public string CustomMethod(string message = "")
        {
            //MessageBox.Show(message, "Message", MessageBoxButton.OK);
            return message.ToUpper();
        }
    }
```

[image: SLCode]

Here is important HTML code.

> Note the `<object id="SLFromJS"`

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server" style="height:100%">
    <div id="silverlightControlHost">
        <object id="SLFromJS" data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="100%" height="100%">
  <param name="source" value="ClientBin/RibbonPoC.xap"/>
  <param name="onError" value="onSilverlightError" />
  <param name="background" value="white" />
  <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="4.0.50401.0" />
  <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
  <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&v=4.0.50401.0" style="text-decoration:none">
   <img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=161376" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight" style="border-style:none"/>
  </a>
    </object><iframe id="_sl_historyFrame" style="visibility:hidden;height:0px;width:0px;border:0px"></iframe></div>
    </form>
</body>
```

5. Hosted Silverlight Application in CRM. For this we need to create two web resources – one to host HTML and second for XAP.
6. Created one more web resource to host JavaScript function. Developer tools (F12) in IE 8 helped me to find exact location of my Silverlight Object (SLFromJS) in HTML DOM. Here is the JavaScript –

> Note window.frames['contentIFrame'].document.forms['form1'].SLFromJS;

```
function CallSilverlightMethod(sender) {
    alert('Inside JS1!');
    var slc = window.frames['contentIFrame'].document.forms['form1'].SLFromJS;
    alert('Inside JS2!');
    if (slc != null) {
        alert('Inside if!');
        alert(slc.Content.SilverlightCode.CustomMethod('Msg From JavaScript'));
        alert('Going out of if!');
    }
    alert('Out of if!');
}
```

My CRM solution looks like following now

[image: CRMSolu]

7. Done! Now test the work by opening link of HTML web resource.

Thanks to following blog posts which I referred.

http://www.a2zmenu.com/Blogs/Silverlight/Calling-Silverlight-Method-from-JavaScript.aspx

[accessing a form that is in an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478078/accessing-a-form-that-is-in-an-iframe)