# Cannot Change InnerHTML of span class?

Tags: javascript, console.log

I'm new to JavaScript and I cannot understand why my html isn't changing?

I have an Iframe and I'm trying to change the .innerHTML of the span class that the Iframe has created in the DOM.

In the DOM structure, the class is called `<span class="weather-location">China</span>`

I'm just trying to access this by changing it's innerHTML to Taiwan instead.

here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
</head>
<body onload="myFunction()">

<iframe class="weather" width="100%" height="600px" frameBorder="0" 
src="(this is my iframe src code)></iframe>

<script type="text/javascript">
   function myFunction() {
      document.getElementsByClassName("weather-location")[0].innerHTML = "Taiwan";
   }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I test it in the console log, it brings up that `weather-location` as `[]` but whats also bizarre is when I use the selector tool to hover on that `weather-location` class and go back and re-type in the code it in the console, it changes the class how I wanted?

Also, I don't know if this helps but when it shows up as `[]` in chrome a little i box pops up saying "value below was evaluated just now".

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478078/accessing-a-form-that-is-in-an-iframe - a frame has its own `document`.

Comment: Imagine this. I call some banking page into mine, via iframe, full page. Than I go around and change elements within that iframe :) just imagine. Fun apart, it's doable if you have *API* access to that iframe or it's actually from your own domain...

Comment: You need to have the script inside the frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change the innerHTML of iframes if it's on **another domain.**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe

This kind of iframe is like a window into another webpage you have no control over.

If it is on the **same domain** you can use something like

```
var ifr = document.getElementById( yourIframeId );
var ifrDoc = ifr.contentDocument || ifr.contentWindow.document;
var theForm = ifrDoc.getElementById( yourFormId );
```

SO Question: [accessing a form that is in an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478078/accessing-a-form-that-is-in-an-iframe)

Credit to : @le_m